# JQuery Datepicker - setting MinDate based on current time

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I'm using JQuery Datepicker for customers to choose a delivery date. I want to be able to check if the customer is ordering before noon and if so next day delivery is available. If they are ordering after noon, next day delivery is unavailable and so that day is unselectable.

I've got some code to check against the current time but how to I add this value into MinDate in the settings at the top?

Thank you!

```js
<div class="delivery-date">
  <p>
    <label for="date">Select a date for delivery below:</label>
    <input id="date" type="text" name="properties[delivery-date]" readonly="readonly" style="background:white; width:30%" class="required" data-error="Please choose a delivery date." />
  </p>
</div>

<script>
jQuery(function() {
  jQuery("#date").datepicker( { 
    // minDate: new Date(((new Date).getTime() + 49 * 60 * 60 * 1000) ), 
    minDate: checkBeforeNoon,
    maxDate: "+2M", // show up to 2 months
    dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
    beforeShowDay: available_delivery_dates 
  } );
});
  

/*==========  check time  ==========*/

// if time before 12pm, offer next day delivery

function checkBeforeNoon(nextDayDelivery){

  var startTime = '12:00 AM';
  var endTime = '12:00 PM';

  var curr_time = getval();


  if (get24Hr(curr_time) > get24Hr(startTime) && get24Hr(curr_time) < get24Hr(endTime)) {
      // before 12pm - next day delivery available
      var nextDayDelivery = '+1d';

  } else {
     // after 12pm - next day delivery unavailable
     var nextDayDelivery = '+2d';
  }

  function get24Hr(time){
      var hours = Number(time.match(/^(\d+)/)[1]);
      var AMPM = time.match(/\s(.*)$/)[1];
      if(AMPM == "PM" && hours<12) hours = hours+12;
      if(AMPM == "AM" && hours==12) hours = hours-12;
      
      var minutes = Number(time.match(/:(\d+)/)[1]);
      hours = hours*100+minutes;
      console.log(time +" - "+hours);
      return hours;
  }

  function getval() {
      var currentTime = new Date()
      var hours = currentTime.getHours()
      var minutes = currentTime.getMinutes()

      if (minutes < 10) minutes = "0" + minutes;

      var suffix = "AM";
      if (hours >= 12) {
          suffix = "PM";
          hours = hours - 12;
      }
      if (hours == 0) {
          hours = 12;
      }
      var current_time = hours + ":" + minutes + " " + suffix;

      return current_time;

  }
}

/*==========  Make sundays always unavailable  ==========*/


function available_delivery_dates(date) {

  var sunday = 0; // unavailable for delivery
  var mon = 1
  var tue = 2;
  var wed = 3;
  var thu = 4;
  var fri = 5;
  var sat = 6;
  
  var day_of_week = date.getDay();
  var not_sun = day_of_week > 0;
  
  if(not_sun){
    var day = date.getDate();
    return [true, ''];  
  }
  else{
    // all else - do not allow
    return [false, ' ', 'Delivery is unavailable on this day'];
  }

  
  
}
  
</script>
```

Comment: Your setting `minDate` as the function and not the returned value, you need to invoke your function... `minDate: checkBeforeNoon(),`

Comment: Thanks but this didn't work

Comment: Also `beforeShowDay: available_delivery_dates()`

Comment: This actually breaks the datepicker altogether. It works fine with with just 'available_delivery_dates' and with minDate as "+2D" but this minDate obviously isn't dynamic

Comment: You aren't returning anything from `checkBeforeNoon()`

Comment: Check my answer below, with other fixes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already accomplished it. You simply need to add a return to the function that is checking if it is noon. If you want to advise the client that one day shipping is available now, you can do so by adding a log in your function. Here is your code modified:

http://jsfiddle.net/graphicfreedom/L3tz8243/1/

```
function checkBeforeNoon(nextDayDelivery){
      var startTime = '12:00 AM';
      var endTime = '12:00 PM';
      var curr_time = getval();

  if (get24Hr(curr_time) > get24Hr(startTime) && get24Hr(curr_time) < get24Hr(endTime)) {
      // before 12pm - next day delivery available
      var nextDayDelivery = '+1d';
      $("#log").html('Next day delivery available! Order before noon!'); //show response to user
  } else {
     // after 12pm - next day delivery unavailable
     var nextDayDelivery = '+2d';
      $("#log").html('Next day delivery NOT available! It is already past noon :('); //show response to user
  }
    return nextDayDelivery;
}
```

Also, you can easily separate the functions. It is easier to read, and you can always call a function from a function. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for this which is helpful, however it returns an error in IE and Safari  "Unable to get property '1' of undefined or null reference"  function get24Hr(time) - is that something you're seeing?

Comment: Oh - it's because I was trying to use server date and time, not client browser time as you are using...

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `var` before `nextDayDelivery` in the `if-else` block as you would be redeclaring it. Then return `nextDayDelivery`. Also, a good idea to fix the missing semi-colons in the `getVal()` method.

```
function checkBeforeNoon(nextDayDelivery) {

    var startTime = '12:00 AM';
    var endTime = '12:00 PM';

    var curr_time = getval();


    if (get24Hr(curr_time) > get24Hr(startTime) && get24Hr(curr_time) < get24Hr(endTime)) {
        // before 12pm - next day delivery available
        nextDayDelivery = '+1d';  // REMOVE var FROM HERE

    } else {
        // after 12pm - next day delivery unavailable
        nextDayDelivery = '+2d';  // REMOVE var FROM HERE
    }

    function get24Hr(time) {
        var hours = Number(time.match(/^(\d+)/)[1]);
        var AMPM = time.match(/\s(.*)$/)[1];
        if (AMPM == "PM" && hours < 12) hours = hours + 12;
        if (AMPM == "AM" && hours == 12) hours = hours - 12;

        var minutes = Number(time.match(/:(\d+)/)[1]);
        hours = hours * 100 + minutes;
        console.log(time + " - " + hours);
        return hours;
    }

    function getval() {
        // ADD MISSING SEMI-COLONS ON THE FOLLOWING 3 LINES
        var currentTime = new Date();
        var hours = currentTime.getHours();
        var minutes = currentTime.getMinutes();

        if (minutes < 10) minutes = "0" + minutes;

        var suffix = "AM";
        if (hours >= 12) {
            suffix = "PM";
            hours = hours - 12;
        }
        if (hours == 0) {
            hours = 12;
        }
        var current_time = hours + ":" + minutes + " " + suffix;

        return current_time;
    }

    return nextDayDelivery;  // ADD RETURN STATEMENT
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this which is helpful, however it returns an error in IE and Safari  "Unable to get property '1' of undefined or null reference"  function get24Hr(time) - is that something you're seeing?

Comment: Oh - it's because I was trying to use server date and time, not client browser time as you are using...